# Show text on next line within the inline elements

Tags: html, css, sass

Can you tell me how to break the date to next line? I have tried many ways. But no luck.

I tried this. But no effect.

```
.not:after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

*.html*

```
       <p class="not">{{item.domain}}
              <em>{{item.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</em>
              <span>
                ${{item.price}}
              </span>
            </p>
```

*.scss*

```
.not {
    line-height: 48px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 15px;
    height: 55px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #56cde0;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 90%;
}

.not span {
    float: right;
    color: #9bb0bf;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

*UI*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost good, simply apply the `\A` trick to the `em` pseudo element

```css
.not em:before {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}

.not {
   line-height: 18px; /*Updated this*/
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 15px;
    height: 55px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #56cde0;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 90%;
}

.not span {
  margin-top:-15px; /*If you want to keep the price on the top*/
  float: right;
  color: #9bb0bf;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p class="not">domain.com
  <em>1990-10-10</em>
  <span>
    $8000
</span>
</p>
```

Comment: There is chang on `.not` class. Please see the edit.

Comment: With that change `date` now shows on top of `domain` name after appling your change. Why?

Comment: @Sampath it's the line-height, remove it

Comment: @Sampath check the update, I reduced the line-height

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: block;` to `em`

```css
.not {
    height: 55px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #56cde0;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 90%;
}

.not span {
    float: right;
    color: #9bb0bf;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
em{
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p class="not">thesite.com
   <span>
 $8800
  </span>
  <em>2018-10-10</em>
</p>
```